# How does Cluster IP handle external traffic and route to pods?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I know **internally** a pod can query DNS (kube-dns) to find the IP of a cluster IP service it wants to connect to. Once it has the IP address it can check its own iptables to forward the traffic to the correct pods (endpoints).

My question is, how does the Cluster IP service handle **external traffic** (coming from load balancer or ingress for example). Both of those would forward the traffic to Cluster IP service and then it does the round robining, but how does Cluster IP service have it's own iptables, is Kube-Proxy watching separately and does it? It wouldn't make sense if the request was forwarded to one of the the endpoints (pods) of the Cluster IP service, they check their iptables, and then forward the request back to themselves, so it must all be happening before it even reaches the pods obviously. Can someone please explain all the steps that happen there PLEASE.

Thank you

Comment: A ClusterIP-type Service doesn't normally handle external traffic at all.  If you have something like an Ingress object that points at the Service, that's frequently internally backed by a Pod running a reverse-proxy server of some sort, at which point you're making a normal Pod-to-Service call inside the cluster.